# Prove: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1 - 2^{b_n})$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $b_n$ be a positive sequence s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$
> converges.
>
> Prove:
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1 - 2^{b_n})$$ converges.

I was thinking about using the comparison test, but I’m not sure how to show $\frac{(1 - 2^{b_n})}{b_n}$ converges.

Any hints on how to show the convergence of $\frac{(1 - 2^{b_n})}{b_n}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use de L'Hospital to show that $(1-2^x)/x \to -\log(2)$ as $x \to 0+$.

Answer (score 1):

For $0\le x\le 1$ we have
$$e^x=1+x\sum_{n=1}^\infty {x^{n-1}\over n!}\le 1+x\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n!}=1+(e-1)x\le 1+2x$$
There is $n_0$ such that $b_n\log 2\le 1$ for $n\ge n_0.$ Hence
$$0\le 2^{b_n}-1=e^{b_n\log 2}-1\le (2\log 2)b_n ,\quad n\ge n_0$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the function $\phi(x)=2^x$ is convex, the function
$g(h)=\frac{2^h-1}{h}$ is monotone nondecreasing. From the convergence if  $\sum_nb_n$ and the assumption $b_n>0$ for all $n$, we have that $0<b_n<1$ for all $n$ large enough. Thus, for all $n$ large enough
$$\Big|\frac{1-2^{b_n}}{b_n}\Big|<\frac{2^1-1}{1}=1$$
By comparison test, it follows that $\sum_n(1-2^{b_n})$ converges absolutely.

Finally, notice that
$$\frac{2^{b_n}-1}{b_n}-\frac{\phi(b_n)-\phi(0)}{b_n-0}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\phi'(0)=\log 2$$
since $b_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.